# FindFirstFile fails on the root path

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, ntfs

I'm using the following code to obtain information about a file system directory:

```
LPCTSTR pStrPath = L"D:\\1";
WIN32_FIND_DATA wfd;
HANDLE hDummy = ::FindFirstFile(pStrPath, &wfd);
if(hDummy != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    //Use 'wfd' info
    //...

    ::FindClose(hDummy);
}
else
{
    int error = ::GetLastError();
}
```

The code works just fine, unless I specify a root path:

- `D:\` - error code `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
- `D:` - error code `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`
- `\\SRVR-1\share` - error code `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME`
- `\\SRVR-1\share\` - error code `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME`
- `\\SRVR-1\HiddenShare$` - error code `ERROR_BAD_NET_NAME`

But it works in the following cases:

- `D:\1` - no error
- `\\SRVR-1\share\1` - no error
- `\\SRVR-1\HiddenShare$\1` - no error

Any idea why?

Comment: The root of a device isn't a normal directory entry, so `FindFirstFile` can't return information about it. You can use calls like `GetVolumeInformation` and `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` to find out various things about a volume.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Thanks. But then I need to know if my path is a root or not. And that creates an additional problem...

Comment: OK. I found that at least I can use `GetFileAttributesEx` for the attributes. That API doesn't seem to treat root path differently from any other path.

Comment: @c00000fd: look at [`PathIsRoot()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773674.aspx)

Comment: IIRC, root directories can also be detected by their lack of a `.` entry (as Jonathan pointed out, root dirs are special)

Answer (score 7):

`FindFirstFile()` is meant to be used to enumerate the contents of a directory. As such it is meant to be used with a file pattern, such as `D:\*`.

When you use `D:\1` you are just using a very restrictive file pattern (`1`) to filter the files in `D:\`, but when you use just `D:\` or `D:` there is no pattern at all!

And the same is true for shared resources. Note that `\\SRV-1\share` does not count as a pattern, because `\\SRV-1` cannot be considered a directory.